# Relinking Tables after an Access Front End is deployed

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I just recently split my Database to a Front End and Backend.  I am deploying the Front End to the Users via E-mail.  they paste the Front End to their DeskTop.  I wanted to include code in the Load Function that will automatically Relink the Tables so that the Relative path to the tables reflects their mapping to the backend.  The code I am using generates the following error:

```
3170 Run Time Error.  Could not find installable ISAM.
```

And, here is the code:

```
Public Function RefreshLinks(strFilename As String) As Boolean
  ' Refresh table links to a backend database - strFilename (full path)
  ' Returns True if successful.
  Dim dbs As Database
  Dim tdf As TableDef

  ' Loop through all tables in the database.
  Set dbs = CurrentDb
  For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
    MsgBox " The table is " & tdf.name
    ' If the table has a connect string, it's a linked table.
    If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
      MsgBox "The table has a connect string."

      tdf.Connect = ";DATABASE= " & strFilename
      tdf.Connect = strFilename
      tdf.RefreshLink ' Relink the table.
      Err = 0
      On Error Resume Next
      tdf.RefreshLink ' Relink the table.
      'MsgBox "The Table is linked"

      If Err <> 0 Then
        RefreshLinks = False
        ' MsgBox "The tables aren't refreshed"
        Exit Function
      End If
    End If
  Next tdf

  RefreshLinks = True ' Relinking complete.
  'MsgBox "The tables are refreshed"
End Function
```

The file name that is passed is `EASDBLocation = "\\RSDATA\RS2\Data2\ComplianceReviews\BusinessReviews\ReviewDatabase\2014 Revised Database\Archive\RAS Database Split Test_be.mdb"`

Comment: Fixed the code formatting and added the Access tag.

Comment: Can you check by removing the spaces from folder and file names? Also check this [MS KB209805 article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209805) related to this issue.

Comment: Look at www.connection strings.com, I think you need more in your connection string

Comment: You have two `tdf.Connect = ...` statements in a row. The first one looks correct, but then the second one overwrites the first one and omits the `;DATABASE=` prefix. Try getting rid of the second one and see if that works any better.

Comment: Unrelated note: `Debug.Print` is usually much more practical than `MsgBox` to debug your code. Especially in loops.